# Construct a Cayley table with respect to composition. Is it associative? commutative? has an identity element?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $S={a, b, c}$ and let $A={\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta}$, where $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$, and $\delta$ are elements of $M(S)$ as follows
$\alpha(a)=a \qquad \alpha(b)=b \qquad \alpha(c)=c $
$\beta(a)=b \qquad \beta(b)=a \qquad    \beta(c)=c$
$\gamma(a)=a \qquad \gamma(b)=a \qquad    \gamma(c)=a$
$\delta(a)=b \qquad \delta(b)=b \qquad    \delta(c)=b$
Construct a Caylet table for A with respect to $\circ$. This table should show that A is closed with respect to $\circ$. Also explain why $\circ$ is associative.
Is $\circ$ commutative? What is the identity element?

I've never constructed a Cayley table before. I know that in order for it to be closed, that every element under $\circ$ should also be in A. but I do not know how to start this. Can anyone give me insight on this?

Answer (score 0):

The description you gave is the group action of the group $A$ acting on the set of symbols $S$. Normally we call $G=A$ and $X=S$, so $G$ acts on $X$ by $g.x$ where $g \in G, x \in X$.

However, the exercise asks for the Cayley Table so it's really asking what happens when $G$ acts on $X=G$.

First, build up the elements of $A$ as permutations. Once you have the permutation elements, build a square matrix $M$ where the matrix element $m_{i,j}$ corresponds to the index of the permutation $g_i \cdot g_j \in G$ inside G (i.e the 2-nd perm composed with the 1-nd perm equals the 2-st perm).